# multiple printf in one statement in c++

Tags: c++, iostream, stdio

hello i am new to this forum and i am a student learning c++! i am handy with cout<< for the purpose of output but now i want to use printf instead.

```
cout<<((2>1)"yes":"no")<<"hello";
```

using these both in one cout statement is possible, but is it possible with printf.
i mean tried the following but it failed! error !

```
printf (  (2>1)?"yes":"no"  );// this gives the output yes but

printf (  ((2>1)?"yes":"no") ("hello")  );//this did not

printf (  ((2>1)?"yes":"no")  "hello"   );// neither did this.
```

Comment: No, none of those is possible. Find the documentation for `printf` (easily located via Google or Bing).

Comment: Personally even if it DID work the way you're trying, I'd opt to split it to two separate statements for readability anyways.

Comment: `((2>1)?"yes":"no")` repeats. Try `static char const * const ny[]={"no","yes"};` once and then use it as `ny[2>1]`

Answer (score 3):

Use a single format string, then choose the parameter values based on your condition:

```
printf("%s %s", (2 > 1) ? "yes" : "no", "hello");
```

or just:

```
printf("%s hello", (2 > 1) ? "yes" : "no");
```

Comment: thnaks alot! luckily i figured it out myself but read your answer later. thanks! and the reason for all the trouble was that i just wanted to save my lines for a particular program.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%s %s", ((2>1)?"yes":"no"), "hello");
```

would give the same output.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler's preprocessor will merge static strings separated by white space, so the following WILL work

```
printf(
   "Now is the time "
   "for all good men "
   "to come to the aid "
   "of their country."
   );
```

No parentheses.  No commas.  Just white-space between static quotes (spaces, tabs, cr, lf)